# iisexpress crashing not able to debug

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to debug my asp.net , which calls a api (which is a 3rd party wrapper). On calling the below method it crashes.

```
private void RegisterCallbacks()
        {
            _instance.Callbacks.RegisterCallbacks(LogCallback, StatusCallback, BusyCallback, ExceptionCallback);
        }
```

Here _instance is of that API. It crashes IIS and no error.. Any ideas what could be wrong?[image]

Getting below in eventvwr

Faulting application name: iisexpress.exe, version: 10.0.14358.1000, time stamp: 0x574fc56b
Faulting module name: HybirRelease32.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x597ec186
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x001cffe7
Faulting process id: 0x814
Faulting application start time: 0x01d315fa7acca3f0
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Test\xxx.dll
Report Id: 32057b9d-8f56-45c9-abc6-64771c99c4ba
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Check the event log and see if it dumped a stack trace.

Comment: Surround the call with a 'try ..catch(exception e){...}', set a breakpoint in the catch body and upon reaching the breakpoint, you should be able to examine the exception data (including stack trace) using a (quick) watch.

Comment: maybe this one RegisterCallbacks call him self again and you crash the iis ?

Comment: Getting below in eventvwr. Faulting application name: iisexpress.exe, version: 10.0.14358.1000, time stamp: 0x574fc56b
Faulting module name: HybirRelease32.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x597ec186
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x001cffe7
Faulting process id: 0x814
Faulting application start time: 0x01d315fa7acca3f0
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
Faulting module path: C:\source\2.4\saamin\bin\xxxxx.dll
Report Id: 32057b9d-8f56-45c9-abc6-64771c99c4ba
Faulting package full name:

Answer (score 0):

Publish the hosted application as debug mode, then go to visual studio debug-> Attach to process -> w3wp.exe(find in 'user name' column your hosted name) select and attach. you can debug the application in IIS host

Comment: Is is probably called `iisexpress` as `w3wp` is the "real" iis. The names has changed throughout the years so I am not sure.

Comment: Even IIS is crashing